# Scrollable gridpane in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, gridpane

im trying to add multiply VBox to a gridpane (called refPane in the following codesnippet) which is inside a scrollpane.

```
    int columnIndex = 0;
    int rowIndex = 0;
    int boxWidth = windowWidth/ITEMS_PER_ROW;
    int boxHeight = windowHeight/ITEMS_PER_COLUMN;

    for(int i=0; i<items.size(); i++){
        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.setPrefWidth(boxWidth);
        vBox.setPrefHeight(boxHeight);

        Label label1 = new Label();
        label1.setText("ImgPlaceholder");
        label1.setPrefWidth(boxWidth);
        label1.setPrefHeight(boxHeight / 100 * 70);
        vBox.getChildren().add(label1);

        Label label2 = new Label();
        label2.setText("Description");
        label2.setPrefWidth(boxWidth);
        label2.setPrefHeight(boxHeight / 100 * 30);
        label2.setPadding(new Insets(0,0,0, 10));
        vBox.getChildren().add(label2);

        refPane.add(vBox, columnIndex, rowIndex);

        if(columnIndex != 0 && columnIndex % GAMES_PER_ROW == 0){
            rowIndex++;
            columnIndex = 0;
        }else {
            columnIndex++;
        }
```

It adds no more then ITEMS_PER_ROW Vboxes in one row and continues in the next row. Also there should be no more rows then ITEMS_PER_COLUM visible.
The problem is, if I add more then ITEMS_PER_ROW * ITEMS_PER_COLUMN to the grid, instead ob beeing scrollable, the vboxes just get smaller in size.

Any Ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are javafx is prioritizing shrinking the VBox's over expanding your grid pane. Try setting the `minHeight` of each VBox, to be equal to its `prefHeight` to keep them from shrinking vertically.